# Execution of a command via Process.Start fails, but works when I execute it directly in the shell

Tags: c#, linux, bash, .net-core, nohup

I am trying to execute the following command on Debian 10 system with dotnet 5:

```sh
bash -c 'cd /home/test/script1 && nohup pipenv run python main.py' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > script1.pid
```

This works flawlessly if the command is executed directly on the shell but not if it is executed via Process.Start():

```cs
var fileName = "bash";
var arguments = "-c 'cd /home/test/script1 && nohup pipenv run python main.py' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > script1.pid";

using var process = new Process
{
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        Arguments = arguments,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        ErrorDialog = false
    }
};

process.Start()
```

Unfortunately, I do not get an error message. The command is simply not executed and is terminated with the exit code 1. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: try `FileName = "/bin/bash"`

Comment: Still the same :-(

Comment: I guess the ` > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > script1.pid` is not a part of the argument? Maybe you could try `eval 'bash ... > ... & ... > ...'`, or call `nohup pipenv run python main.py` and redirect stderr with you C# code.

Comment: I've got it working now. The command is: `bash -c "$(bash -c 'cd /home/test/script1 && nohup pipenv run python main.py' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > script1.pid)"`. I don't think this solution is the best, but at least it works. Thanks for your help!